# dialogflow: does not recognize entity despite trained 100% the same

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an entity "restaurant"
I trained an intent with the sentence "Wo ist das restaurant?" ( german for 'Where is the restaurant')

Now if I try it out it does not recognize the entity in the exact same sentence as trained. It did for several weeks but stopped working now.

What debugging steps should I take? I am at a loss on how to systematically trace this unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Was the language the problem, or was it something else?  I'm experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're saying is true. I've tested this behavior. This could be because of following reasons:

You've created your agent in `English as default language` & then have added `locale German`. Now, what you're doing is testing your bot in `web demo` (default chat window created by api.ai) & not in `test console` (given at side tab of your screen).

Now, answer to your question is, when you create an agent in `English as the default language`, api.ai offers you a web demo that supports `English` only & when you test `german statements` there, it won't answer. You should try it out for other `integrations channels` or at `test console`, it will definitely work.

1. This does not work here cause default language of an agent is not `German`.
   [image]
2. Instead, you should test your statements here or at other `integration` channels
   [image]

Or else, create a new agent & while creating only select `German as default language` & then go to `integrations` tab & then test it out at `web demo`. You'll definitely be able to test your bot there.

3. Now, it works here cause default language of an agent is `German` only.
   [image]

Now, I don't know why api.ai have structured like this but this is how it is. Hope you've got my point.